# Text over top caret

Tags: css, menu, scroll, overflow, caret

I have a dropdown menu with fixed height and when I want to scroll down, the text is hidden below the top caret.
What can I do to make the text visible in the caret also?

[image]

I'm not using any image for the caret.Everything is done using CSS.
This is my code:

```
<div class="arrow_box">

    <div class="content">

       .... text ....

    </div>

</div>

.arrow_box {
position: relative;
background: #88b7d5;
border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
top:20%;
text-align: center;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
bottom: 100%;
left: 50%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
border-width: 30px;
margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
border-width: 36px;
margin-left: -36px;
}

.content{
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
overflow-y:auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: please include your code in the question.

Comment: Can be multiple options to solve your issue an extra container or just padding or top or margin .... all depends of your code.

Comment: Well,we can't say anything if we can't look at your code, but i would try with giving the higher z-index to the element where text is. Also you must overlap this two elements. Right now, element where text is starts at the bottom of the carret. So anything you do will not work if you not overlaping this two elements

Comment: The caret it's actually a border, so that's why your text scrolls beneath. If you'll use two overlapping divs the scroll bar will be too long and it will look nasty. You might want to reconsider the caret size or another design